# segmentation fault 11 during a circular linked list node addition at the beginning of the list

Tags: c

When I created the program at first I could create the circular linked list with addition of only the first initial node.

As soon as I try to add the new node at the beginning then it gives me a Segmentation Fault 11.

I even tried to search Stack Overflow for this problem but many of them have just dereferenced the pointer variable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *start=NULL;
struct node *create_cll(struct node *);
struct node *display(struct node *);
struct node *add_beg(struct node *);
struct node *add_end(struct node *);
struct node *del_beg(struct node *);
struct node *del_end(struct node *);
struct node *del_aftgiven(struct node *);
struct node *del_entire(struct node *);

int main()
{
    int option;
    do
    {
        printf("\n\n****MAIN MENU****");
        printf("\n\nEnter an option from the list given below");
        printf("\n1. Create a linked list");
        printf("\n2. Display the linked list");
        printf("\n3. Add a node at the beginning of the list");
        printf("\n4. Add a node at the end of the list");
        printf("\n5. Delete a node from the beginning of the list");
        printf("\n6. Delete a node from the ending of the list");
        printf("\n7. Delete a node after a given node");
        printf("\n8. Delete the entire linked list");
        printf("\n");
        scanf("%d",&option);

        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: start = create_cll(start);
                    printf("\nCircular linked list created!");
                    break;

            case 2: start = display(start);
                    break;

            case 3: start = add_beg(start);
                    break;

        }
    }while(option!=4);
    return 0;
}

struct node *create_cll(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *new_node,*ptr;
    int num;
    printf("\nEnter -1 to stop adding new nodes");
    printf("\nEnter the data:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if(num!=-1)
    {
        new_node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new_node->data=num;
        if(start!=NULL)
        {
            while(ptr->next!=start)
            {
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next=new_node;
            new_node->next=start;
        }
        else
        {
            new_node->next=new_node;
            start=new_node;
        }
    }
    return start;
}

struct node *display(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr=start;
    while(ptr->next!=start)
    {
        printf("\t %d",ptr->data);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\t %d",ptr->data);
    return start;
}

struct node *add_beg(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *ptr,*new_node;
    int num;
    printf("\nEnter the data you want to enter at the beginning:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    new_node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data=num;
    if(ptr->next!=start)
    {
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next=new_node;
    new_node->next=start;
    start=new_node;
    printf("Node succesfully added:");
    return start;
}
```

Comment: In `create_cll()` I don't see where you initialize `ptr`.

Comment: ... also in `create_cll` you need to loop until the user enters `-1`. There is no loop here...

Answer (score 0):

`ptr` in

```
while(ptr->next!=start)
```

is unassigned, and using `->` will cause an error. Try putting `ptr = start` on the line before it. This will also happen in `add_beg()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting segmentation fault because, in the function `create_cll()`, the `ptr` pointer is used uninitialized:

```
    if(start!=NULL)
    {
        while(ptr->next!=start) // ptr is uninitialized
        {
             ......
             ......
```

Initialize `ptr` with `start` before using it, like this:

```
    if(start!=NULL)
    {
        ptr = start;
        while(ptr->next!=start)
        {
             ......
             ......
```

Same problem in `add_beg()` function:

```
if(ptr->next!=start) // ptr is uninitialized
```

Also, this should be in loop instead of `if` block as you want the `ptr` to point to node in the circular list whose next is pointing to `start`. So, you should do:

```
    ptr = start;
    while (ptr->next!=start)
    {
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
```